# JPanel overlapping image in JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing

Trying to add an image in JLayeredPane but when I add two JPanel in JLayeredPane they are overlapping JLayeredPane Image Propery Below is my code.

```
void display()
{
    windowFrame.setLayout(null);
    windowFrame.setResizable(false);
    windowFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    windowFrame.setSize(500, 555);
    windowFrame.setLocation(50, 50);

    mainPanel.setLayout(null);
    mainPanel.setSize(500, 555);

    leftPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 555);
    rightPanel.setBounds(200, 0, 300, 555);

    // Adding these two properties overlapped Main Image
    mainPanel.add(leftPanel);
    mainPanel.add(rightPanel);

    backgroundImageLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 555);
    backgroundImageLabel.setOpaque(false);

    // adding image in JLayeredPane
    mainPanel.add(backgroundImageLabel);

    windowFrame.add(mainPanel);

    windowFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

I want to add JPanel in my JLayeredPane so that I can differentiate these two screens. I'm not familiar how to use JLayeredPane and JPanel I did some work in JFrame but using JPanel is not my thing. Any help or suggestion....

Comment: Don't use a null layout on your frame. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not familiar how to use JLayeredPane

Then start with the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) for a working example.

Download the example and customize the example for your exact requirement. NOt only does the tutorial show you how to use a layered pane it shows you how to better structure your code so that all your components are created on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: OkThanks for your suggestion i'll read this now, but can you tell me why JPanel overlapping Image of JLayeredPane

Comment: I can't tell what you are doing based on a few random lines of code. Read the tutorial to learn a new concept instead of guessing.